# Locating comments moved to chat

Tags: support, comments, chat

So I add a comment to a question and I can track the question I commented on by digging into my profile and looking at my history.

But it turns out that this was a contentious question and a large number of people also added their own comments and someone came along and moved them all to chat as they are want<sup>1</sup>.

But the process of doing this removes my comment from my profile history so now I can't easily go back to the question.

Is there a way to locate my original comment after it has been moved to chat?  Or if not, can a message be inserted into my history saying that comments on a particular question/answer were moved to chat?

---

1. While I understand the reasoning behind the moves, I am somewhat miffed every now and again as the comments are moved in bulk, and *my* comment was obviously not a part of the rest of the riff-raff's, and so should have remained!

Comment: Sometimes the rif-raf start to drag down a post's score by deliberately misrepresenting an answer, and the mods just move it all.  It's annoying, but sometimes it's the only way to stop the dumpster fire

Comment: @RichardU But its always other peoples comments that are the fuel for the dumpster fire - it's never *my* comments :D

Comment: Yep, I feel the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more roundabout than it should be, but you can see your recent chat messages on your [chat account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/207951/peter-m?tab=recent).

It's roundabout because there's no direct link from your profile (or your network profile) to your chat profile; you have to go to [the list of chat users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users) and search for yourself.  If you have a common name, that can be a pain.

Alternatively, if you've ever chatted, the transcript will contain those messages and they link to your profile.

If all else fails, feel free to ask a moderator for help finding your chat profile.  We have extra tools.

Comment: That is round about.  Is there anyway to go from my profile to that link directly?

Comment: Alas, no.  I'll try to find (or create) a feature request on main meta about that.  Moderators have a link, so I don't see why users can't.  (We got that link relatively recently, so I suspect it wasn't possible at some point in the past and then didn't get revisited.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can go to [the chat page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) and click on your profile at the top. You might also be able to look at the "Mine" tab there, but I don't have any active, so I can't tell if that would work.

Comment: @DavidK are you automatically logged in to chat?  I can't remember what that's like on a first-time visit (don't remember if I had to log in or it was automatic).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Mine is automatic, but I'm also automatically logged on to all of my SE sites on this computer. Not sure how it would look to someone who had never used chat before.